# Exception : run sonar analyses from jenkins (SonarQube 6.4)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm using Jenkins ver.2.7.4.

I successfully launch sonar analyses from Jenkins by invoking top-level Maven targets **sonar:sonar** with SonarQube 5.1.2.

But when I upgrade SonarQube to version 6.4 I got this error when trying to launch a new build from Jenkins :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXX: 
Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:6.4.0.25310 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failure to find org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:6.4.0.25310 .......
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you changed the version of the *maven-plugin* to 6.4. This is not correct.

The current version of the [sonar scanner for maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.3.0.603) is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.603</version>
</dependency>
```

It will work with recent versions of SonarQube, like SonarQube 6.4.